# Ansible > how to specific cronjob check

Tags: cron, ansible

I have so many cron jobs running in specific user. Try to check individual cron jobs is enabled or not. Moreover, everyday on some period, I will check by ansible.

```
- name: cronjob for test script
  remote_user: {{root_user}}
  become: true
  cron: 
    user: "{{ app_user }}"
    name: "test script"
    hour: 20
    weekday: 6
    job: "/bin/bash {{test}}/test.sh >> {{test}}/test-cron-error.log 2>&1"   
  tags:
    - deploy_test

- name: enable for test script
  remote_user: {{root_user}}
  become: true
  cron: 
    user: "{{ app_user }}"
    name: "test script"
    hour: 20
    weekday: 6
    disabled: no
    job: "/bin/bash {{test}}/test.sh >> {{test}}/test-cron-error.log 2>&1"   
  tags:
    - enable_deploy_test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cron module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cron_module.html) to maintain a crontab for specific user by specifying `user` parameter. To periodically check the state of your crontabs, you can set a cron job running your playbook on your ansible master, if you have one. To ensure that your crontab doesn't contain other entries, you can remove all cron files before using the playbook, however you need to be sure that those "rewrites" are not happening at the same time as your jobs.

**EDIT:** Your cron task creates a cron job right away, there is no need to call the same task with `disabled: no`. If you have a task with cron module with `state=present` (this is default) and without `disabled: yes` - it will set a job as you defined.

Comment: How can check on some period it's enabled or not? Can you give me an example?

Comment: if we want to disable cron then we can use `disabled: yes` and for enabled `disabled: no`. but this is not fulfilled my requirement

Comment: I want to check specific cron job status (enabled|disabled)

Comment: @Ifti, Ansible is good at _confirming_ a required state and not-so-good at _listing_ the current state, so as Andrew suggests, you can delete all entries and enforce yours with Ansible, periodically.